# Underscore being appended to mounted disk name after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ubuntu-10.04, path

I have Upgraded Ubuntu from version 9.10 to 10.04. Now when I mount any of my extra hard disks the drive name gets an underscore appended to it, as shown below. Which obviously messes up all my pahts. How do I prevent\correct this?

```
/media/<drivename>_
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I had a number 1 being appended to my name with Ubuntu 14.04/mount from util-linux 2.20.1. The answer below was the same resolution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look through your /media folder. My guess is that even when no drive is plugged in, its mountpoint exists. remove this (empty) directory (with the drive unplugged, just to be safe), with `sudo rm -r /media/drivename`. Hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: ...because the Gnome automounter creates a new */media/drivename* mount point for stuff it automounts (and deletes it when unmounted).  so if the default exists, the automounter will append the underscore to get a mount point that doesn't exist.  (i suspect the existing mountpoint will be used if there's a corresponding */etc/fstab* entry for it.  but i haven't tested this theory.)

Comment: What causes this to happen in the first place? From my end, nothing unusual happened. When I started up my computer one day, I noticed that a new folder in media had been created (/media/$USER/<drivename>1 so a number had been appended) and the original folder (/media/$USER/<drivename>) showed up in nautilus as having an "x" next to it, with a size of ?